# Ignoring parent dependsOn field in form submit in laravel nova

Tags: php, laravel-nova

In my laravel nova resource i'm returning these fields:

```
            Select::make('department_id')->onlyOnForms()
                ->options(\App\Models\Department::pluck('title', 'id')),

            Select::make('Sector', 'sector_id')->onlyOnForms()->rules(['required'])->dependsOn(['department_id'],
                function (Select $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
                    // query available sectors based on choosed department
                    if ($formData->department_id)
                        $field->options(\App\Models\Sector::pluck('title', 'id'));
                    else
                        $field->readonly();
                }),
            Text::make('subject'),
```

The problem is **department_id** is only used for getting the **sector_id** value and there is no such field in Model and database column.
But when the form is submitted i got this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'department_id' in 'field list'
> at ....

how can i make nova ignore that field on submit ?

Comment: Can you show your model class ? May be explicitly defining `$fillable` attributes in Model class will ignore the `department_id`